# Update multiple divs in one page with one jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm looking for a way to make the below piece of code generic. My aim is to update multiple div's (as I will have around 100) on one page with one script. With the structure below, I have to have one script per DIV. 
My return string from the webservice_getall.asp can return the value based on the parsed parameter (they look like this: K2,C16,B2 and so on
Any help is appreciated.

My current code looks like this:

```
<body>



<div id='content1'>Loading...</div> 
<div id='content2'>Loading...</div> 
<div id='content3'>Loading...</div> 
<div id='content4'>Loading...</div> 
 ......
<div id='contentN'>Loading...</div> 
</body>


</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').show();

            },
            complete: function() {

                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {

                $('#content').show();
            }
        });


        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("webservice_getall.asp?request=contentN");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('webservice_getall.asp?request=contentN');
        }, 1000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: are you asking how to select multiple divs that start with 'content' like the jquery selector `jQuery('div[id^="content"]')`  That will return all divs that start with 'content' (e.g. content_1 or content1)

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: No the other way around - splitting the string into multiple containers, so the first value goes into "content(1)" or "content_1), the Next value into "content(2)" or "content_2" so I can use them in vairous Places. Now, with the "content" I have, I get the full string instead on only one value from the string.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, with the "content" I have, I get the full string instead on only one value from the string.

In that case, it will depend somewhat on the format of your return. I will assume that you are just getting back a single text string that is comma separated. If you are getting a JSON return or anything else, you will need to modify this to suit.

First, you will need to turn your returned value into an array. That's easy enough with javascript's [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.
**Note**: You have not described your content very well. This method assumes that your example content is representative, and that there will never be chunks of content with commas *inside* them: that is, commas will **only** ever be used to separate content elements. Personally I would normally json encode everything and work with that, but that's me.

Once you have an array, you can use an appropriate selector and the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate through your divs and put the corresponding fields from the array into each div.

**Note:** I chose a naive method of doing this that assumes you will always start with `id=content1` on the page... or that if you aren't doing so, you will always return the appropriate starting value in your array for whatever your starting content is (since it would be trivial to include our starting index no when calling your server, and then returning from there the correct number of elements from that start point).

At this point, your code would look something like this:

**TODO** replace `"webservice_getall.asp?request=allcontent"` with whatever `get` query string you're using to call for all content at once. You haven't made that very clear, since your example in your question is apparently your old code.

```
<body>

<div id='content1'>Loading...</div> 
<div id='content2'>Loading...</div> 
<div id='content3'>Loading...</div> 
<div id='content4'>Loading...</div> 
 ......
<div id='contentN'>Loading...</div> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup( {
      cache: false,
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#content').show();
      }, 
      complete: function() {
        $('#content').show();
      }, 
      success: function() {
        $('#content').show();
      }
    });
    $.get("webservice_getall.asp?request=allcontent", function(contentReturn){
      contentReturn = contentReturn.split(',');

      $('div[id^="content"]').each(function (index) {
        $(this).html(contentReturn[index]);
      });
    });
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $.get("webservice_getall.asp?request=allcontent", function(contentReturn) {
        contentReturn = contentReturn.split(',');

        $('div[id^="content"]').each(function (index) {
          $(this).html(contentReturn[index]);
        });
      });
      },
      1000);
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</html>
```

Here's an [example of this in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H33UC/14/) (obviously not using AJAX, but it's a working demonstration of the principle).

Because this way only iterates each div element once using a single selector, it should be fairly decent performance (as opposed to, for instance, iterating the array and using a new selector for each array element to address each div--not that there aren't better ways if you wanted to iterate the array instead, just as an example of what not to do). The caveat is that I don't know how it will perform on a truly large page, especially with the entire page depending on the single AJAX call.

I also don't know why you're calling `show` on `#content` repeatedly, but I left it alone. I assume you know what you're doing with it and will act accordingly. Since you showed so little detail on your new WIP solution, I simply adapted what you gave. Hopefully it shows you where to go, I can't promise it will work as is with how little detail you gave.

Comment: This looks promising - thank you so much.
The content will alway be stripped from commas inside the elements (it will be like "red,blue,green,Black"). I will test and play around with it and hopefully get it to Work. Thanks Again!

Comment: Hopefully it works, please do let me know if it does or if not what issues it has =)